# Disable wordpress css on subdirectory

Tags: css, wordpress

Ok this is almost a repost except I know the cause. Ok So I have a site in a subdirectory under my www folder (which appears to simply be a link to the public_html folder.) Anyhow this site is not a wordpress site, even though the parent site is. My wp-admin wp-content and wp-includes directories are also in the same spot.

My problem is that the second site in the subdirectory is automatically using the wordpress css for some reason. I do not want it to do that. I have a css file for it, but it does not load it and uses the wordpress one instead.

Is there a way to correct this so that it only uses the css file I tell it to use?

Comment: if it is in online server can you share it's link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed this. I simply renamed the css file to something other than style.css In this case I name it santastyle.css as this site is meant to work as a secret santa website. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that this site will use the Wordpress CSS is if it somehow imports the Wordpress CSS. View the page source and try do discover from where the site is getting the Wordpress CSS. Make sure that you are not calling the  tag anywhere. If you have managed to strip away the Wordpress CSS, then just reference the desired CSS as you would with a static HTML site. The fact that it is in the same directory as the Wordpress directories will not make a difference.

Comment: This was not at all helpful... as I showed in the question that was exactly what was happening, also by renaming the css being the answer, it did have to do with the wordpress css which was showing when I clicked on the style.css link in the show page source